# Date conversion with strptime()

Tags: python, datetime

What is the best way to convert the following *date pattern* to a `datetime.date` object in Python?

```
1st April
8th April
15th April
1st May
```

Comment: I thought of inelegant solutions, such as removing the "st", "nd", "rd" and "th" suffix through a regex and then parsing via `strptime()`. Anyone has something better in mind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dateutil.parser` will parse almost every known date format:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
parse('8th April')
```

To always get a date in the future:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
from datetime import datetime

d = parse('8th April')
if (d - datetime.now()).days <= 0:
    d = datetime.date(d.year+1, d.month, d.day)
```

Comment: Can you set the `parse` method to always return a future date? E.g. if it's `1st April` can it return `01-04-2013` instead of `01-04-2012`?

Comment: @JosvicZammit you can supply a datetime instance with default values in the default kwarg: `parse('8th April', default=datetime.date(2013, 1, 1))`

Comment: @mensi, I think a default doesn't work because the problem is more complicated.

Comment: If you give a default date with a nonsense year, you can check the result and replace the nonsense with the current year; then if the result is less than today, add a year.

Comment: @MarkRansom I adjusted my answer to hopefully solve it in a clean way

Comment: @mensi Doesn't work, however you did answer the original question. Will put a new question about this. Maybe someone knows an "elegant way" to do it.

Comment: @mensi New question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130091/default-future-year-when-effecting-date-conversion-with-dateutil).

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

val = val.replace('th', '').replace('st', '')
d = datetime.strptime(val, '%d %B')
```